# Isomorphism of semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have $\varphi,\psi : H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$, so that $\varphi = \operatorname{Ad}_g \circ \psi$ where $\operatorname{Ad}_g:N\to N$ is given by $n\mapsto gng^{-1}$ for some $g \in N$.

Prove that $N \rtimes_{\varphi} H \cong N \rtimes_{\psi} H $.

I understand it's not the same conditions as here: [When are two semidirect products isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527800/when-are-two-semidirect-products-isomorphic#comment1128508_527800)

Comment: Find an isomorphism between the two groups.  Remember that an element of a semidirect product can be written as an ordered pair.  So where should $(n,h)$ map to?

Comment: So, I think it is not true, but i can't find example.