# Distinctness of semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> We have two groups $X$ and $Y$ of prime order, when is semidirect product defined from different homomorphism to the automorphism group same?

I have read [When are two semidirect products isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527800/when-are-two-semidirect-products-isomorphic)
but it may be easier to determine when the order of the groups are primes.

**My try**
I don't see why can they be isomorphic. We have two distinct homomorphisms and therefore $1$ maps to distinct automorphisms of $H$. For semidirect products to be same, image of $1$ should be the same automorphism, by the way we define product in the external semidirect product.

Please help.

Comment: There is only one non-abelian group of order $pq$ which is the semidirect product $C_p\rtimes C_q$ up to isomorphisms where $p,q$ are distinct primes.

Comment: @Bach, can you prove it? That all semidirect products are isomorphic in this case irrespective of the homomorphism we choose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Structure of groups of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502186/structure-of-groups-of-order-pq-where-p-q-are-distinct-primes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that might help: Let $X$ have order $7$ and $Y$ have order $3$. These groups are cyclic; write $x$ for a generator of $X$ and $y$ for a generator of $Y$. Let $\phi\colon X \to X$ and $\psi\colon X \to X$ be the automorphisms $\phi(x) = x^2$, and $\psi(x) = x^4$.

Notice that $\phi^3(x) = x^{2^3} = x^8 = x$, and $\psi^3(x) = x^{4^3} = x^{64} = x$, so as automorphisms of $X$, $\phi$ and $\psi$ each have order three.

I claim that $X\rtimes_\phi Y \cong X\rtimes_\psi Y$. Indeed, (abusing notation slightly) $X\rtimes_\phi Y$ and $X\rtimes_\psi Y$  are generated by $x$ and $y$, so to specify a homomorphism, I just need to tell you where $x$ and $y$ go, and then check that the map I've written down indeed defines a homomorphism. I claim that the map $x \mapsto x$, $y \mapsto y^{-1}$ is such a homomorphism and moreover that it is an isomorphism. I'll leave it to you to check this.

---

So if the answer has to be "sometimes" and not "never," maybe we should reconsider what should be true based on this example. Aut$(X)$ is generated by $x \mapsto x^3$. There is an automorphism of Aut$(X)$ that sends the automorphism $x \mapsto x^3$ to the automorphism $x \mapsto x^5$. Under this automorphism of Aut$(X)$, $\phi$ is mapped to $\psi$.

So some questions to investigate: if we have $\phi$ and $\psi$ in Aut$(X)$, will  it be the case that $X\rtimes_\phi Y\cong X\rtimes_\psi Y$ whenever there is some automorphism $f\colon$ Aut$(X) \to $ Aut$(X)$ such that $f(\phi) = \psi$? Is this the only condition?

Comment: Where I am confused is the following. $Y$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{|Y|}$ and $Aut(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{|X|-1}$, taking a homomorphism here, semidirect products are same iff $\Phi_1(n)(m)=\Phi_2(n)(m)\forall n\in\mathbb Z_{|Y|} ,m\in\mathbb Z_{|X|-1}$ . Now, by property of homomorphisms, this happens iff $\Phi_1(1)(1)=\Phi_2(1)(1)$, which cannot happen because $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are distinct homomorphisms. Please clarify.

Comment: Here is the false statement: "semidirect products are isomorphic if and only if $\Phi_1(n)(m) = \Phi_2(n)(m)$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z_{|Y|}$ and $m\in\mathbb Z_{|X|-1}$." I have given an example above that proves that the "only if" direction is false.

Comment: That is a doubt. Without this, how is multiplication same in semidirect product by two homomorphisms, because $(x_1,y_1).(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+\Phi(y_1)(x_2),y_1+y_2)$

Comment: Ahh. You seem to be using two groups are "the same" to mean "identical". I am using "the same" to mean "there exists a group isomorphism from one to the other."

Comment: I am not getting what $\Phi:Y\to Aut(X)$ are you taking.

Comment: I guess if we identify $Aut(X)$ with $\mathbb Z_6$, then $\phi\colon Y \to Aut(X)$ is $1 \mapsto 2$. $\psi\colon Y \to Aut(X)$ is $1 \mapsto  4$.