# Conjugate images induce isomorphic semi-direct products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4781422/prove-there-is-a-unique-non-abelian-group-of-order-75) for the question context.

Let $H_5 = \Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5$. I am trying to prove that for all non-trivial homomorphism $$\varphi:\Bbb Z_3\to \operatorname{Aut}(H_5),$$ the resulting semi-direct products $$\Bbb Z_3\ltimes_{\varphi} H_5$$ are all isomorphic. I know $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(H_5)\right| = 2^5\cdot 3\cdot 5$ so the non-trivial image of $\varphi(\Bbb Z_3)$ are all conjugates to each other as Sylow $3$-subgroups in $\operatorname{Aut}(H_5)$. If we take non-trivial homomorphisms $$\phi,\varphi:\Bbb Z_3\to\operatorname{Aut}(H_5)$$ I am guessing if we write $$\varphi(\Bbb Z_3) = \gamma\phi(\Bbb Z_3)\gamma^{-1}$$ for some $\gamma\in\operatorname{Aut}(H_5)$ then $$\Bbb Z_3\ltimes_{\phi} H_5\to \Bbb Z_3\ltimes_{\varphi} H_5, (x,y)\mapsto (x, \gamma(y))$$ should be an isomorphism.

But I am having trouble to prove that it is a homomorphism. What I will need is $$(x_1x_2,\gamma(\phi_{x_2}(y_1)y_2)) = (x_1x_2,\varphi_{x_2}(\gamma(y_1))\gamma(y_2)),$$ or that $$\varphi=\gamma\circ\phi\circ\gamma^{-1}$$

This requires stronger condition than $$\varphi(\Bbb Z_3) = \gamma\phi(\Bbb Z_3)\gamma^{-1}$$ which we don't have. How should I proceed?

Comment: I think you just didn't do the computations properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just didn't do the calculations properly.

Let $C_n$ denote the cyclic group of order $n$ (so I don't have to type $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which is harder to $\LaTeX$ and can also be confused with the $5$-adic integers. Let $H=C_5\times C_5$.

Let $\varphi,\theta\colon\mathbb{C}_3\to\mathsf{GL}_2(5)$ be two nontrivial homomorphisms. We want to show that $H\rtimes_{\varphi}C_3\cong H\rtimes_{\theta} C_3$. This will require some specific facts about your specific orders, since the result is not true in general.

An element of order $3$ in $\mathsf{GL}_2(5)$ satisfies $X^3-1=(X-1)(X^2+X+1)$. Since both factors are irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5$, it means that the minimal polynomial is either $X^2+X+1$ or $X-1$; in the latter case it is the identity, which we are excluding, so the minimal polynomial is $X^2+X+1$. That means that matrix for this element (with, say, the standard basis for $C_5\times C_5$) must be conjugate to the companion matrix of $X^2+X+1$. Thus, any two elements of order $3$ in $\mathsf{GL}_2(5)$ are conjugate in $\mathsf{GL}_2(5)$. That is, there exists an automorphism $\psi\colon H\to H$ such that $\theta = \psi\varphi\psi^{-1}$.

If we denote the automorphism $\varphi(y)$ by $\varphi_y$, and the automorphism $\theta(y)$ by $\theta_y$, we have that for each $y\in Y$, $\theta_y = \psi\varphi_y\psi^{-1}$.

(Note: I write my semidirect products backwards from how you write them: the first coordinate lies in the normal subgroup, the second in the "acting" group. So the product in $A\rtimes_g B$ is $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2) = (a_1g_{b_1}(a_2), b_1b_2)$. You can translate this to your notation..)

Define $f\colon H\rtimes_{\varphi}C_3 \to H\rtimes_{\theta} C_3$ as follows:
$$f(x,y) = (\psi(x), y).$$
We have
$$\begin{align*}
f(x,y)f(r,s) &= (\psi(x),y)(\psi(r),s)\\
&= \Bigl(\psi(x)\theta_y\bigl(\psi(r)\bigr),ys\Bigr)\\
&= \Biggl(\psi(x)\biggl(\psi\Bigl(\varphi_y\bigl(\psi^{-1}(\psi(r)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr),ys\Biggr)\\
&= \Bigl(\psi(x)\psi\bigl(\varphi_y(r)\bigr),ys\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(\psi\bigl(x\varphi_y(r)\bigr),ys\Bigr)\\
&= f\Bigl(x\varphi_y(r),ys\Bigr).
\end{align*}$$

Now note that in $H\rtimes_{\varphi}C_3$, we have
$$(x,y)(r,s) = (x\varphi_y(r),ys).$$
Therefore, we have that
$$f\Bigl((x,y)(r,s)\Bigr) = f(x,y)(r,s).$$
The map $g\colon H\rtimes_{\theta}C_3 \to H\rtimes_{\varphi}C_3$ given by $g(x,y) = (\psi^{-1}(x),y)$ is a homomorphism by the same argument, and it is clearly the inverse of $f$, so $f$ is an isomorphism, as desired.

The calculation shows that in general, if $\varphi,\theta\colon K\to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$, and there exists $\psi\in\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ such that $\varphi=\psi\theta\psi^{-1}$, then $N\rtimes_{\varphi}K\cong N\rtimes_{\theta}K$; the result is not restricted to finite groups.

Comment: The linear algebra part is what I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: @user108580 That just proves the existence of $\psi$; but that is not what you are asking in the post... the post is asking why conjugate actions yield isomorphic semidirect products. That comment makes no sense.

Comment: I believe your $\psi$ is exactly the $\gamma$ that I am asking for that conjugates with $\phi$ and $\varphi$. This is the only part I am missing as written in my question.

Comment: @user108580 No... your post states that you are having trouble proving that the map I denote as $f$ is a homomorphism. That map already assumes the existence of your $\gamma$. If **that** was your question, then your post **does not** ask that question. Your post is asking for a proof that $f$ is a homomorphism, not for a proof that $\gamma$ exists.

Comment: @user108580: I mean, look at the title of your post! It says "conjugate images induce isomorphic semidirect products?" Not "are any two of these actions conjugate?"